# Использование теневых свойств в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

В чем заключается необходимость использования теневых свойств? Вот пример кода с https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Почему нельзя просто инициализировать binding?

```
binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сокрытие свойства может делаться по нескольким причинам:

1. Избегание лишних проверок на not-null. Это как раз то, что есть в примере из вопроса. Выглядит следующим образом:

   ```
   private var _property: Type? = null
   private val property: Type get() = _property!!
   ```

   Причем `_property` инициализируется один раз - в конструкторе. Так как инициализация свойства происходит однократно и в конструкторе - на практике там никогда не будет содержаться `null`. Однако, для того, чтобы код скомпилировался необходимо задать какое-то значение для `_property`. Kotlin - null-safety язык, то есть при каждом обращении к свойству, способному содержать `null`, необходимо проводить соответствующую проверку. Чтобы не делать проверку каждый раз, мы создаем новое свойство `property`, уже неспособное хранить `null`, и при обращении к нему возвращаем `_property!!`. Заметьте, что возможность наличия `null` здесь игнорируется, но только один раз, в дальнейшем об этом можно забыть. Это как отмахнуться от назойливой мухи - муха особо не мешает, но работать приятнее без нее.

   Следует заметить, что это костыль. На Kotlin более правильно было бы написать так:

   ```
   private lateinit var property: Type
   ```

   Собственно, `lateinit` при компиляции создаст код полностью аналогичный тому, что приведен изначально, а у Вас не будет лишнего свойства.

   **Update**

> lateinit в данном случае не подойдёт, потому что в фрагменте байдинг нужно очищать в onDestroyView, а для lateinit нельзя задать null

2. Сокрытие приватного свойства.
   Бывает так, что Вам нужно иметь какое-то свойство, которому может назначаться новое значение внутри класса, но не снаружи. Причем поле должно быть доступно всем (публичное). Многократно встречал в этих случаях такой код:

   ```
   private var _property: Type = ...
   val property: Type get() = _property
   ```

   Здесь `_property` приватно и доступно только внутри класса, а `property` - публично и доступно всем. При этом свойству, объявленному через `val` новое значение присвоить нельзя, а при объявлении через `var` - можно. Ровно то, что нам и требовалось. Однако, и тут есть более короткий способ, более правильный в Kotlin:

   ```
   var property: Type = ...
       private set
   ```

   Как и в предыдущем случае, под капотом скрывается примерно то же, что было написано изначально, но программист не мучается с двумя разными именами.
3. Сокрытие типа свойства. Насколько мне известно, это - единственный случай, когда Kotlin не предоставляет красивого и короткого решения. Выглядит следующим образом:

   ```
   private val mutableList: MutableList<Type> = mutableListOf<Type>()
   val list: List<Type> get() = mutableList
   ```

   Имеет смысл только если одно из свойств видимо для большего числа пользователей. В примере я привел список, но это может быть любая подобная структура. Внутри класса программист может добавлять новые элементы в `mutableList`, но снаружи класса - только читать их, без изменения списка! Наиболее часто применяется в андроиде к структурам данных (список, ассоциативный массив, множество и т д) и объектам типа `LiveData`.
   Как правило, есть некий класс (1), хранящий `MutableLiveData` и изменяющий состояние. И есть другой класс (2) - читающий из первого (1) это состояние. Тот, кто читает (2) НЕ должен изменять ничего, только смотреть. Тот, кто изменяет (1) - должен иметь возможность и смотреть и изменять. Надеюсь, достаточно понятно.

Comment: `lateinit` в данном случае не подойдёт, потому что в фрагменте байдинг нужно очищать в `onDestroyView`, а для `lateinit` нельзя задать `null`

Comment: @IR42 спасибо, я и правда не задумался об очистке, добавлю в ответ